# how to download local network file via browser

Tags: javascript, html, networking, activex

I want to give a link of network local file in browser, where users can open from there.

link would be like this  file.xls

In IE6,7,8 it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is a network local file? Is it served over HTTP? In which browsers does it work? How is it not working in IE (does it print some error message)?

Comment: local file is something like <a href="file:///C:/test.txt">file 3</a>

and browser is IE 6,7 and 8

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **File URI scheme**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme